# Error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when child calls parent function

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

We have a parent component which is passing a function to the child component. Here is code for parent component

```
....
const getChildUpdate = (name) => {
   console.log(name)
   setName(name)
}
return(
    <div>
        <ChildComponent callback={getChildUpdate} />
    </div>
)
....
```

In child component I want to call this call back function at the time component load and only once. Here is the code for the child component

```
....
useEffect(() => {
    callback('User Name')
}, [])
....
```

But when I execute, the callback function is called many times (not once) and I see below-mentioned issue

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I can't figure out the route cause and a fix.

Comment: Guessing, since there's not enough here to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The callback is causing a state update in the parent which makes it re-render, which makes the child re-render. Post a more complete example and we can help you useCallback or something to avoid that.

Comment: Yeah that is the case. Call back is updating state in the parent. How to handle such cases?

Comment: Generically, without seeing your component? I believe I'd do useCallback in the parent so the function always points to the same thing regardless of parent re-renders, and in the child useEffect, pop callback into that dependency array.

Comment: @Nikki9696 that wont work as we are passing some other props as well to child component.

Comment: @Nikki9696 and even if I remove setName from getChildUpdate, I still get same issue.

Comment: Please post a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)